# How to remove Google Analyticator in Wordpress site?

Tags: google, google-analytics

I have issues in uninstalling Google Analyticator. Should I just ignore it and install Google Analytics for Wordpress instead?

Comment: Could you expand on the problems you're having? Can you not delete the plugin in the usual way?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually uninstall plugins by removing the plugin folder in /wp-content/plugins and if need be drop the tables involved in phpmyadmin.

Steps to add Google Analytics to your wordpress sites:

1. Go to Appearance, Editor. Choose header.php
2. Paste the GA code above the  tag
3. Save the header.php

Comment: You should also try to deactivate the plugin in the wordpress installed plugins directory and then delete it from there, manual removal should be a last resort.

Comment: Hi guys,
Thank you for the replies. Apparently, I do not have the Appearance, Editor. Choose header.php. Or maybe I can't seem to find it. Now, I don't know where to put the GA tracking code. In my site's GA tracking status, it only says tracking installed. I  guess I should just wait for 24 hours before I would know if my installation went smoothly? I also check the source code of my site and I can't find GA tracking code. This might be a stupid question but I'll ask away anyway, GA can't track my site properly without the tracking code written on my site right?

Comment: Should I just paste the code manually?